# Есть ссылка "выйти" при нажатии должен выполниться php код

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Всем привет, у меня меню состоит из списка,ссылки, есть ссылка выйти с аккаунта, вот что я сделал

```
$("#logoutusers").click(function(){

    var loguser = $("#logoutusers");

        $.post("./pages/logout.php",{

        logoutuser : loguser

    },

    function(data){

    });     
});
```

Ошибок не выдает, но выдает какую ошибку в самой библиотеке `jquery`, мне надо просто удалить сессию `ajaxом`, вот сам код `logout.php`

```
<?  
if(isset($_POST['logoutuser'])){

    unset($_SESSION['sender']);

    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Что не так?

Comment: Ну дык посвятите нас, что за ошибка то? Что пишет? )))

PS А зачем это вы серверу в logoutuser ссылку на объект передаете? Не представляю зачем оно вам понадобилось? Даже не в курсе как jQuery себя поведет.. Может от этого и ошибка? Отправьте просто  logoutuser:"Y".
PPS Путь к файлу ./pages/logout.php лучше заменить на абсолютный. 

Comment: про val() забыл, добавил проверил, ни одной ошибки не выходит. Условие в пчп добавил елсе даже он не отвечает.

Comment: Ух ё, кажется вы попались на мою "любимую" ошибку, тоже всегда попадаюсь, уже много лет))) В php в первой строке надо стартовать сессию, чтобы можно было с ней хоть что-то сделать session_start() Ппоробуйте, должно помочь. Ну и на совет Crasher-а обратите внимание.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#logoutusers")` вернёт вам `nodeList`, тоесть список обьектов. Вам же нужно получить значение, следовательно, стоит использовать метод `.val()`. Так же, стоит сделать `callback`, тоесть чтобы `php` файл возвращал что-то, тоесть было `echo` результата.

Answer (score 0):

Самый оптимальный вариант и не нужно мудрить. Создай файл logout.php и на него ссылку прямую "выход". При нажатий удалите сессию и откроет вам главную страницу.

```
<?
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/");
exit;
?>
```